# Map external directory outside tomcat installation in eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I want to map an external directory outside tomcat installation which stores images in eclipse Dynamic Web Project's tomcat server. I have done that in tomcat directly by adding context tag in server.xml file. But when I done that in eclipse Dynamic Web Project's tomcat server.xml file. It is not working. I am using Tomcat 6.

My question is:

- How to map an external directory outside tomcat installation in eclipse Dynamic Web Project?
- Is it the good way to map external directory outside tomcat installation?

Thanks

Brajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a linked resource. Go to the folder in which you want your external directory to apprear. Now open the File menu -> New -> Folder.

Type in the name.

Click on "Advanced >>". Select "Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)". Browse to the external directory.

Click Finish.

That creates a link from your workspace to the external directory. It's possible that the plugin supports that.

Comment: It worked. But its not updating the linked directory with new added files in that directory. When manually refreshing the linked directory in eclipse after that it shows new files.

Comment: Refresh automatically option is bydefault disabled. Even if I enabled that option still new files are not showing in linked directory.

Comment: The refresh can take a moment. If it doesn't work within, say, 10 seconds, please file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: Had some troubles with this until i realized that I need to add my /war folder to "Deployment Assembly"